# Включение стандартной тени у окна с переопределённым шаблоном

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, окно

Стиль:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Window}">
    <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="True"/>
    <Setter Property="ResizeMode" Value="NoResize"/>
    <Setter Property="WindowChrome.WindowChrome">
        <Setter.Value>
            <WindowChrome NonClientFrameEdges="None" CornerRadius="0" GlassFrameThickness="0" ResizeBorderThickness="0" CaptionHeight="30"/>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Window}">
                <Border BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="DarkGray" Background="#F0F0F0">
                    <Grid>

                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                        <!-- TitleBar -->
                        <Border Background="White" Grid.Row="0"/>

                        <!-- Window content -->
                        <AdornerDecorator Grid.Row="1">
                            <ContentPresenter/>
                        </AdornerDecorator>
                    </Grid>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

**Вопрос**

Каким образом для моего стилизированного окна я могу включить стандартную тень:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вопрос, конечно, легко решается, если установить `WindowChrome.GlassFrameThickness` в -1, но это имеет "побочный эффект": ухудшение качества шрифта.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Для меня такой результат неудовлетворителен ):
Поэтому, требуется альтернативное решение включения стандартной тени (не  брезгуем и WinApi).

**P.S.:** У вас могут возникнуть предложения по поводу улучшения качества конкретно шрифта, но сразу скажу, что это всё бесполезно. Вы можете сколько угодно играться с `TextOptions`, `SnapsToDevicePixels`, `UseLayoutRounding` и т.д. и т.п. (кстати говоря,  текст приведённый на картинке уже `Display`), и всё равно ничего из этого не выйдет! Проблема не в шрифте, а в настройке окна.

**UDP:** Не нужно так же предлагать `WindowStyle` установить в `None` и налепить тень внутри шаблона. Это совсем другое. Я говорю именно о *стандартной тени*. **`WindowsStyle` не должен меняться**!